# Как вывести сразу несколько различных ошибок в форме не в одном месте?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, form

Здраствуйте, есть код формы :

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/inc/submit.php" class="form__brief" id="form__brief">

    <div id="note"></div>

    <div class="form__section">
        <label for="nameFull">Як до вас звертатись ?*</label>
        <input name="nameFull" class="form__input" id="nameFull" type="text" placeholder="Алекс Бойко, просто Алекс" title="Скажіть, як до вас звертатись ?" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form__section">
        <label for="nameCompany">Яку компанію представляєте ?</label>
        <input name="nameCompany" class="form__input" id="nameCompany" type="text" placeholder="Моє дитя: google" title="З ким ми будемо співпрацювати ?">
    </div>

    <div class="form__section">
        <label for="communication">Як з вами краще зв'язатись? *</label>
        <textarea name="communication" class="form__input" id="communication" placeholder="Номер телефону, емейл, телеграм, вайбер, соц. мережа, голубина пошта." title="Оберіть зручний для вас спосіб зв'язку" maxlength="2000" min="3" value="message" wrap="hard" rows="8" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form__section">
        <label for="more">Опишіть свою компанію, та, що дійсно хочете в ній покращити</label>
        <textarea name="more" class="form__input" id="more" placeholder="Ми займаємось бруківкою та хочемо розробити власний бренд, сайт на який будуть переходити потенційні клієнти з реклами та соціальних мереж. У нас вже є сайт, але його зробили за 300$ і він відверто дуже поганий, не те чого ми чекали" title="Оберіть зручний для вас спосіб зв'язку" maxlength="2000" min="3" value="message" wrap="hard" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
        
    <div class="brief__btn">
        <!-- <input class="btn" id="form__brief_btn" type="button" value="Відправити голуба"> -->
        <button class="btn" id="form__brief_btn" type="submit" data-uri="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>">Відправити голуба</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

код jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#form__brief").submit(function() {
        var uri = $('#form__brief_btn').attr('data-uri');
        var marker_url = uri + '/inc/submit.php';
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: marker_url,
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg == 'OK') {
                    result = '<div class="ok">Сообщение отправлено</div>';
                    $("form").trigger("reset");
                }
                else {result = msg;}
                $('#note').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Код php :

```
<?php
    $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
    if($post) {
        $nameFull = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameFull']));
        $nameCompany = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameCompany']));
        $communication = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["communication"]));
        $more = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['more']));
        $error = '';
        if(!$nameFull) {$error .= "Вкажіть як до вас звертатись ? ";}
        if(!$communication) {$error .= "Вкажіть один або більше варіантів зв'язку з вами";}
        if(!$error) {
            $address = "aborigen19961202@gmail.com";
            $mes = "Ім'я: ".$nameFull."\n\nНазва компанії: ".$nameCompany."\n\nСпосіб зв'язку: " .$communication."\n\nДеталі: ".$more."\n\n";
            $send = mail ($address,"Заявка",$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nReply-To:$nameFull\r\nFrom:$nameCompany <contact>");
            if($send) {echo 'OK';}
        }
        else {echo '<div class="err">'.$error.'</div>';}
    }
?>
```

Все вроде работает, но в случае нескольких ошибок, выводит их вместе.
[image: Вид ошибки при текущем коде]

Как реализовать вывод каждой ошибки над полем где она возникла и предоставить этим полям другие стили ? Буду очень благодарен за подсказку!

Comment: Возвращать с сервера не строку-json с указанием места ошибки и текста ошибки. На клиенте соответственно парсить json и подсвечивать место ошибки

Answer (score -1):

Собирай ошибки в массив например `array_push($error, "Вкажіть як до вас звертатись ?");`
и в конце делаешь цикл с выводом всех ошибок по очереди

```
 foreach ($error as $value) {
    echo ('<div class="err">' .$value.'</div>');
  }
```

Comment: Надо внимательнее прочитать вопрос. данный цикл просто добавит теги, а выесь вывод все равно будет в одном месте.

Comment: тогда лучше это через jquery сделать

Comment: можно, но не обязательно. в любом случае ответ сейчас неверный